# is it possible to issue spatial gremlin queries against orientdb?

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

i am exploring the capabilities of [orientdb](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb), and in general am trying to stick with [gremlin](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/) for theoretical portability across graph databases.

i see that orient has provided this new [spatial module](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Spatial-Module.html) with their latest 2.2 version.

the examples provided use [orient's sql dialect](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL.html#orientdb-sql-dialect).

it's not clear to me if issuing spatial queries requires orient sql, or if there is a way to use gremlin for spatial queries.

can someone with experience shed some light on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but it's not possible to use Gremlin for this purpose, because in Gremlin there is not such concept. You can use the OrientDB SQL to do that.